# Flutter how to create a banner across an image

Tags: flutter, dart, frontend, flutter-design

New to flutter and trying to recreate a website but cant figure out how to have text over my card and include the full width opacity behind the text. I also tried to add rounded corners to the card but I'm noticing that there are still white sharp corners. any advice would be greatly appreciated!.

[This is what Im aiming for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRJhx.png)

[This is what I currently have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbXpQ.png)

```
  Card(
    elevation: 5,
    child: Container(
      height: 300,
      width: double.infinity,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
          image: DecorationImage(
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            image: AssetImage(urlImage),
            colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1), BlendMode.softLight),
          )),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Expanded(
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Text(
              title,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 24,
                backgroundColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 5.0),
  );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are receiving the white corners is because you have different radius on the Card element and the Container, you can fix this by setting a shape of RoundedRectangleBorder with your preferred radius.

Regarding the text background, you can get what you want if you wrap the Text inide a full width Container and set the background to the Container instead of the Text.

Here's a example:

```
  Card(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
    ),
    elevation: 5,
    child: Container(
      height: 300,
      width: double.infinity,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
          image: DecorationImage(
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            image: AssetImage(urlImage),
            colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1), BlendMode.softLight),
          )),
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(15.0),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(15.0)),
            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
          ),
          width: double.infinity,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Text(
            text,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 24,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 5.0),
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

The key for the border radius is to use a `ClipRRect` in the content of the `Card` with the same border radius as the card.

To position the badge over the image use a `Stack` with a `Align`

A reusable widget could be this:

```
class MenuItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const MenuItem({
    Key? key,
    required this.imageUrl,
    required this.label,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String imageUrl;
  final String label;

  static const double cornerRadius = 100;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(cornerRadius),
      ),
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(cornerRadius),
        child: Stack(
          fit: StackFit.expand,
          children: [
            Image.network(
              imageUrl,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.4),
                height: 100,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    label,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 26,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The result looks [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rXGh.jpg)

Comment: Stack and Align with Alignment.bottomCenter are very clean for this specific case, I came to give this exact same answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you notice your image you can see above your image there is a text .In this type of case we use `Stack` widget in flutter.The first item of the `Stack` will be at the bottom and the next item will be above it. We use `Position` to set the second item position above the first item. Here I post a code with your expected out put format

```
Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(15),
              topRight: Radius.circular(15),
            ),
            child: Image.network(
              'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/20/Spaghetti_Bolognese_mit_Parmesan_oder_Grana_Padano.jpg/800px-Spaghetti_Bolognese_mit_Parmesan_oder_Grana_Padano.jpg',
              height: 250,
              width: double.infinity,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            bottom:0,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.black54,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                vertical: 5,
                horizontal: 20,
              ),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children:const [ Text(
                    'Spahegeti',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 26,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    softWrap: true,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                  ),
                ]
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
```